# inotify_init() Function Falied

Tags: c++, inotify, inotifydataerrorinfo, inotify-tools

I installed [inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) and plugin code into my 
existing code for watch file.I am always getting message that `inotify failed`.

I googled and found that kernel should with inotify option.(Not sure how will I check as I am using remote machine).

I have added all shared library in compilation.( does not relate but in case any possibility)

`Linux machinename 2.6.9-89.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 10:33:05 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Any idea How can I debug the issue as I am using inotify tool first time

```
inotify = inotify_init();
         if(inotify<0)
         {
             loginfo<<" inotify_init fail"<<inotify<<endl;
         }

 output = -1
```

Comment: Have you examined `errno`?

Comment: Yes but Not able to figure out

Comment: Thanks for putting negative before putting any feedback about the issue

Comment: I am having this issue, please where can I find the errno? Kinda new to kernal APIs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done analysis and found that inotify does not work less than 2.6.13 kernel version.It was the primary reason I was getting error and did not get desire result